# Theming ttk widgets

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to do something simple -- change the fill color of a ttk Entry widget in a Python script to show an invalid entry.  My question is not specifically how to do this (though I'd like to know!) but rather how to figure out how to do this given generally available documentation and resources.

I've read everything I can find about ttk and styles (including several StackOverflow questions), and while the process of applying styles looks straightforward if you know all the keywords/options you need, I can't figure out how to approach the problem if the keywords/options are unknown.

For an accepted answer to this question, I'd like to see the process of figuring out how to set the background color of a ttk Entry widget, that leads to a solution that works with Python.  I want to learn to fish.

Comment: You may want to take a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65464537/13629335). Its true ttk related to tkinter isnt good documented.

Comment: I recommend going through the content on tkdocs.com

Comment: @Bryan As I remember, tkdocs.com is a good starting point but not a full description. For example, I remember having a hard time to figure out that you can get a layout for the items in the layout of the widget as well.

Comment: @Atlas435: correct, it is not a full description, but it provides a good starting point. It has a [whole section](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html) on understanding the basics of theming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, SO isnt designed to substitude regular [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#module-tkinter.ttk) or [tutorials](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html). But I agree with the OP that ttk lack a little bit of a overall description.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle
```

ttk isnt imported by tkinter itself and needs to be explicitly imported. It is recommended to import it as ttk to avoid name conflicts.

```
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use('default')
```

The [style class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style) is designed to manipulate the styling database.
Themes are always used, even if you didnt defined one. A list of themes can be found [here](https://ttkthemes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/themes.html) or [here](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes). Or you can define your own with [theme_create](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style.theme_create), like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65461962/13629335)

```
button = ttk.Button(root, text='abc')
button.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
style_name = button.winfo_class()
```

Every `ttk.widget` has the styling option and can be adressed by `.winfo_class`

```
style.layout(style_name,
             [('Button.border', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'border': '1', 'children': [
                 ('Button.focus', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                     ('Button.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                         ('Button.label', {'sticky': 'nswe'})
                         ]})
                     ]})
                 ]}
               )])
```

Manipulating the layout gives you trivial options like to have a button on the right or left side. But in addition with [element_create](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style.element_create) it can be a powerfull tool. Like [Scrollbar.thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64538934/how-to-change-the-width-of-a-tkk-scrollbar-in-a-custom-style), [Scrollbar.trough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29583609/13629335), [Downarrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59023075/13629335).

```
print(style.layout(style_name))
print('Layout')
```

Get the current layout and try this with different themes and may mix them together with element_create or try to use the [vsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049803/how-to-create-a-search-box-with-magnifying-glass-image-and-some-text-within-it) under windows/visual_styles_api.

```
print(style.element_options('Button.label'))
print('label')
print(style.map(style_name))
print('map')
```

---

To simply [configure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style.configure) some [colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17383836/13629335) I have found, and linked in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65464537/13629335), a list of colors that can be configured but [dosent mean they necessary have an effect](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html#whydifficult).

> Options that are available don't necessarily have an effect, and it's
> not an error to modify a bogus option.

For your entry background configure `ttk::style configure TEntry -fieldbackground color` that can also be found in the list of colors.

```
widget = ttk.Entry(root, text='abc', style='My.TEntry')
style.configure("My.TEntry",
                 foreground="grey",
                 fieldbackground="black")
```

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle

bg_color = '#091424'
fg_color = '#ffcfcf'
arrow_bg = '#8c101e'
border_color = '#db994c'
highlight_color = '#372940'
pressed_color = arrow_bg

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use('clam')#background/arrowcolor

frame =tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

widget = ttk.Spinbox(frame, text='abc', style="my.TSpinbox")
widget.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

style_name = widget.winfo_class()

style.layout('my.TSpinbox',
             [('Spinbox.field', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                 ('Spinbox.background', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                     ('Spinbox.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                         ('Spinbox.innerbg', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                             ('Spinbox.textarea', {'expand': '1', 'sticky': 'nswe'})
                             ]})
                         ]}),
                     ('Spinbox.uparrow', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': 'nse'}),
                     ('Spinbox.downarrow', {'side': 'bottom', 'sticky': 'nse'})
                     ]})
                 ]})
              ])



style.configure('my.TSpinbox',
                background=bg_color,
                foreground=fg_color,
                arrowcolor=arrow_bg,
                arrowsize=20,
                relief="raised",
                bordercolor=border_color,
                lightcolor='red',
                darkcolor='green',
                troughcolor='pink',
                )

style.map("my.TSpinbox",
          arrowcolor = [('pressed', pressed_color),
                        ('active', highlight_color),
                        ('disabled', '#ffffff')])


print(style.layout(style_name))
print('Layout')
print(style.element_options('Spinbox.field'))
print('field')
print(style.element_options('Spinbox.downarrow'))
print('downarrow')
print(style.element_options('Spinbox.uparrow'))
print('uparrow')
print(style.element_options('Spinbox.padding'))
print('padding')
print(style.element_options('Spinbox.background'))
print('background')
print(style.element_options('Spinbox.textare'))
print('textarea')
print(style.element_options('Spinbox.innerbg'))
print('innerbg')
print(style.map(style_name))
print('map')
```

---

**Additional References**:

- [Motivation behind ttk](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/48.md)
- [Introduction to the theme engine](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_intro.html)
- [ttk theme engine](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_style.html)
- [ttk.widget](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_widget.html)
- [ttk.image](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_image.html)

Comment: Before posting this, I had looked at both the documentation and tutorial links you provided.  They were helpful in learning about how styling works in general, and of course the specific illustrations were useful for those specific cases, but neither is a good general reference to what is possible and how.

Comment: @Watusimoto thats exactly what I stated in the first place. See *But I agree with the OP that ttk lack a little bit of a overall description.*. Therefore I spent some time to gather these information to give you an idea of what is possible. I updated my answer with additional references.

Comment: The style.layout() seems to show how the various elements and subelements are organized.  I had intuited this, but it was helpful that you made it explicit.  In order to set the background color of the spinbox's text area, I can look at the list of color/options you linked to and get there after a little trial and error.  I think one of the things that has tripped me up is that it appears that, maybe, fieldbackground for TEntry just does not work on Windows.  At least I haven't been able to get it to do so.

Comment: I just tried a very simple example, and was able to get fieldbackground working with TEntry widgets, so something else is going on.  I can no longer edit my comment to remove that complaint.

Comment: Ah... it works on most themes, but not "vista".  Blargh.